# Store the status of the registration is not working properly (is always stored the value "C"but "I" should be stored if the registration is paid)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form in the conference registration page for the user to register in a conference The form has the action below:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('conferences.storeRegistration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])}}">
...
</form>
```

A conference can have 1 or many registration types and a registration type can be free or paid. Depending on the registration type(s) selected by the user, when the form is submitted, in this `storeRegistration()` I want to store in the status column of the registrations table the value "C" (complete) if the total price of the selected registration types is "0" but if is ">0" I want to store as "I" (incomplete).

For that in the storeRegistrationInfo() Im trying to get get value in the session 'total' and then use a ternary '`status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',`' like below:

```
 public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator)
    {
    ...
    $total = Session::get('total');

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $registration = Registration::create([
            'conference_id' => $id,
            'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
             'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',
        ]);

    ...
}
```

But it's not working, is always stored in the column 'status' the value C', independently if the registration has paid tickets or if all tickets are free. The issue should be because dd($total) shows "null".

Do you know how this can be properly achieved?

---

**Sequence flow of the issue:**

I have a conference details page where the user can select in a form the quantity of tickets that he wants for the conference. A conference can have 1 or many tickets associated, and some can be free other paid. So in this form for the user to select the tickets that he wants and then clicks "Next". The form has this action:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('conferences.storeQuantities', ['id' => $conference->id, 'slug' => $conference->slug])}}">
...
</form>
```

So when the user clicks in "Next" the code goes to the RegistrationController storeQuantities() this method stores the selected tickets (quantity of each ticket, total, etc) and some other some info in the session and returns the user to the 'conferences.registration' route:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
        ]);

        $rtypeQuantities = $request->get('rtypes');

        $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        $total = 0;
        foreach ($rtypeQuantities as $rtypeName => $quantity) {

            if ($quantity) {

                $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name', $rtypeName)->firstOrFail();
                $price = $rtype->price;

                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['price'] = $price;
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
                $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;

                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions'] = $rtype->questions;
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['id'] = $rtype->id;
            }
        }
        Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
        Session::put('allParticipants', $allParticipants);
        Session::put('customQuestions', $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);
        Session::put('total', $total);

        return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]))->with('total', $total);
    }
```

So then the code goes to the route:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@displayRegistrationPage',
    'as'   =>'conferences.registration'
]);
```

So the function displayRegistrationPage is then called and it gets the values in session and redirects the user to the registration page:

```
  public function displayRegistrationPage(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {

        $selectedRtypes = Session::get('selectedRtypes');
        $allParticipants = Session::get('allParticipants');
        $customQuestions = Session::get('customQuestions');




        if (isset($selectedRtypes)) {
            return view('conferences.registration',
                ['selectedRtypes' => $selectedRtypes, 'allParticipants' => $allParticipants, 'customQuestions' => $customQuestions, 'id' => $id,
                    'slug' => $slug]);
        } else {
            return redirect(route('conferences.show', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
        }
    }
```

So now the registration page is presented to the user. Here there is a form for a user to register introduce some data to register in a conference. The form has this action:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('conferences.storeRegistration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])}}">
...
</form>
```

So, when the form is submited, in this storeRegistration() I want to store in the status column of the registrations table the value "C" (complete) if the registration that the user is doing has only free registration types. But I want to store the value "I" (incomplete), if there are 1 or more registration types, have a price > 0. Because the user then later needs to pay so the registration stays incomplete until he pays.

```
 public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator)
    {
    ...
    $total = Session::get('total');

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $registration = Registration::create([
            'conference_id' => $id,
            'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',
        ]);
        ...
    ...
}
```

Full RegistrationController:

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{


    // handles the form of the conference details page where the user select the tickets
    public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
        ]);

        $rtypeQuantities = $request->get('rtypes');


        $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;


        $total = 0;
        foreach ($rtypeQuantities as $rtypeName => $quantity) {

            if ($quantity) {

                $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name', $rtypeName)->firstOrFail();

                $price = $rtype->price;

                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['price'] = $price;
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
                $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;

                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions'] = $rtype->questions;
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['id'] = $rtype->id;
            }
        }


        Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
        Session::put('allParticipants', $allParticipants);
        Session::put('customQuestions', $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);
        Session::put('total', $total);

        return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]))->with('total', $total);
    }

    // redirects the user to the registration page
    public function displayRegistrationPage(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {

        $selectedRtypes = Session::get('selectedRtypes');
        $allParticipants = Session::get('allParticipants');
        $customQuestions = Session::get('customQuestions');


        if (isset($selectedRtypes)) {
            return view('conferences.registration',
                ['selectedRtypes' => $selectedRtypes, 'allParticipants' => $allParticipants, 'customQuestions' => $customQuestions, 'id' => $id,
                    'slug' => $slug]);
        } else {
            return redirect(route('conferences.show', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
        }
    }

    // handles the registration form of the registration page
    public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator)
    {

        $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
        $user = Auth::user();

        $total = Session::get('total');


        $rules = [];
        $messages = [];

        if (isset($request->participant_question_required)) {
            $messages = [
                'participant_question.*.required' => 'Fill all mandatory fields.',
            ];

            foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                $rule = 'string|max:255'; 

                // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
                if ($value) {
                    $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                }

                // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
                $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
            }
        }

        if ($allParticipants == 1) {

            $rules["participant_name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
            $rules["participant_surname.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';

        }


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'conference_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',
            ]);

            $participants = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++) {
                $name = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_name[$i] : '';
                $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_surname[$i] : '';
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => $name,
                    'surname' => $surname,
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'registration_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

                ]);
            }

            if (isset($request->participant_question)) {
                foreach( $request->participant_question as $key => $question ) {
                    $answer = Answer::create([
                        'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
                        'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id,
                        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
                    ]);
                }
            }

            return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]).'#myTickets');

        }
    }
}
```

Context layout: https://ibb.co/b0VN8T

Comment: check var_dump($total), may be it is string "0"

Comment: Why is `total` stored in a session instead of being calculated by the return form request data?

Comment: Thanks, the total is calculated with the request data in storeQuantities() with "$selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
                $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
                $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;" only then is stored in the session. But I dont know if this is a correct approach besides not working.

Comment: The var_dump($total); shows NULL.

Comment: It seems like a multi-part form, it might even be beneficial to store everything on the front end, then submitting it all in 1 go

Comment: The storeQuantities() is a method that receives the request from the conference details page and redirects the user to the registration page. Then in the registration there is a form and when the form is submited the code goes to the storeRegistrationInfo() method that receveis the request data of the registration form. Its not a multi step form, each method is for a differente page (store quantities() method handles the conference details page select tickets form and storeRegistrationInfo() handles the registration form of the registration page ).

Comment: Its a scenario like this: https://ibb.co/b0VN8T.

Comment: Did you check the value of "total" using $request inside your displayRegistration and storeRegistration ?
Laravel Documentation suggests to store and retrieve value using
$request->session()->put('total', 'total');

$total = $request->session()->get('total');

You can also use the global session function mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#using-the-session)
I would also do a **"dd($total)"** inside these functions to check its value from the point you are storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]))->with('total', $total);
```

You have stored your data into the session in a premanent way, but just when you wanted to redirect, you erased the first stored one:

```
Session::put('total', $total);
```

with:

```
...->with('total', $total);
```

The last one, is flashing the data into your session for only the next request (when you displayed the registration form), so when you sent the registration form for submission, the "total" data has already vanished from the session.

Remove the:

```
...->with('total', $total);
```

And it will be ok for you.